# Automate gitlab project creation and push to repository

Tags: shell, github, gitlab, devops, cicd

Since I have more than 100 projects to be created in Gitlab, is there a way that creation till push to repository can be automated.
Create project->Clone the repo.->Push modified files.
This flow needs to be automated.
Please provide me reference incase of no specifics.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you migrating from one place to another? Such as from github.com to gitlab.com?

Comment: @AdamMarshall no, I am just creating multiple java services and have to host them on gitlab. I need scripts which can ease my process of creating project, cloning and pushing them back in complete automated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projects don't have to be created in advance. You can just push to any namespace to create projects.

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab.example.com/mynamespace/my-newproject.git
git push -u origin --all
```

You'll see the server respond back with a message like this:

```
remote: The private project mynamespace/my-newprojct was successfully created.
```

If you wanted a script to create a project from scratch, you might do something like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# create-project.sh
gitlab_host="gitlab.example.com"  # replace with your host
project_path=$1
project_name="$(basename "${project_path}")"
mkdir "$project_name"
pushd "$project_name"
echo "# ${project_name}" > README.md
# Put any additional project file creation steps here
git init
git checkout -b main
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin "ssh://git@${gitlab_host}/${project_path}.git"
git push -u origin main
popd
```

Usage:

```
./create-project.sh mynamespace/my-newproject
```

This will create a directory `my-newproject`, setup repo files, remote, and push it to GitLab creating the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to call create-project.sh inside a .bat file which is not possible. Kindly suggest how to get these commands which I can call from .bat file also

Comment: @Meenal the same principal works in a `.bat` file. The important parts are really only the git commands. Only a few adjustments would be needed for handling variables to be valid bat syntax. For example using `%1` instead of `$1` and `%project_name%` instead of `${project_name}`.... you _can_ also use bash on Windows.

Comment: gitlab_host="gitlab.com"  # replace with your host
gitlab_port="2222"
project_path=%1
project_name="%basename% "%project_path%""
mkdir "%project_name%"
pushd "%project_name%"
echo "# %project_name%" > README.md
# Put any additional project file creation steps here
git init
git checkout -b develop
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin "ssh://git@%gitlab_host%:%gitlab_port%/%project_path%.git"
git push -u origin develop

Comment: Please have a look at my changes on your script. Does it look good.

Comment: @sytech does it require any type of settings to be changed? I've tried this approach but it doesnt seems to work as I get `fatal: 'ssh@git@dummy-gitlab-instance.local/my-group/test-project.git' does not appear to be a git repository`